# How can I add the British Columbia holidays to my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, calendar

In [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/), I can search for `British Columbia,` (Calendar/other calendars/Browse Interesting Calendars) and get all the vacation dates for that province, as a long list of dates, which may be added to my calendar one by one.

Is there a way to add all BC holidays to my calendar, in a similar way as I'd add `Christian Holidays` or `holidays in the United States?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot import those holidays via Google Calendar itself, you can add them through an external source such as:

https://holidays.kayaposoft.com/public_holidays.php?country=can&region=British+Columbia&year=2018

This site provides ICS URLs that can be imported, eg:

https://www.kayaposoft.com/enrico/ics/v1.0?country=can&fromDate=01-01-2018&toDate=31-12-2018&region=British%20Columbia&en=1

for the 2018 BC vacation dates in english.

Comment: one year only was annoying, soI changed the toDate year part to 2219, figured I wouldn't need it more than 200 years later... :P